# Cullen and frey graph. Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values

Tags: r

I extracted the data from [here](https://ckan.publishing.service.gov.uk/dataset/trees-in-camden), Trees_In_Camden.csv. I wanted to examine the distribution of heights as well as the tree count, so I wrote the following:

```
install.packages("fitdistrplus")
library(fitdistrplus)
descdist(Trees_In_Camden$`Height In Metres`, discrete = F, boot=200)
descdist(Trees_In_Camden$`Number Of Trees`, discrete = T, boot = 200)
```

Unfortunately, I received this error message, which persisted even after I removed the NA values.

```
> descdist(Trees_In_Camden$`Height In Metres`, discrete = T, boot=200)
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
> descdist(Trees_In_Camden$`Height In Metres`, discrete = F, boot=200)
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
```

I have also checked if the data is numerical.

```
> is.numeric(Trees_In_Camden$`Number Of Trees`)
[1] TRUE
> is.numeric(Trees_In_Camden$`Height In Metres`)
[1] TRUE
```

What is happening?

Comment: Your question will likely be closed at some point as it is considered off-topic for this site. This is likely something that can be easily debugged if you look hard enough.

Comment: Are you sure you've removed the `NA` values from your data? I just quickly pulled in your data and had no trouble running `fitdistrplus::descdist()`.

Comment: I tried `t_h <- na.omit(Trees_In_Camden$`Height In Metres`)` and `descdist(t_h, discrete = F, boot=200)`. Unfortunately, I received this error message  `Error in descdist(t_h, discrete = F, boot = 200) :  data must be a numeric vector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `na.omit`, the function returns a modified object. In your case, the object returned is no longer a vector (which is why `fitdistrplus::descdist` throws the error).

You can see this behaviour in the first two lines of that function:

```
if (missing(data) || !is.vector(data, mode = "numeric")) 
stop("data must be a numeric vector")
```

So the question is, what is `na.omit` returning? If you look up the specific method for that function using:

```
methods("na.omit")
[1] na.omit.data.frame* na.omit.default*    na.omit.ts*         na.omit.vctrs_vctr*
see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```

If you then look at the `na.omit.default` function we can see this behaviour:

```
if (any(omit > 0L)) {
   names(omit) <- nm[omit]
   attr(omit, "class") <- "omit"
   attr(object, "na.action") <- omit
}
object
```

That is, the function returns the `NA`-omitted data but also assigns an attribute to the object. This attribute, named `'na.action'` is simply a vector of class `omit`.

Without digging any deeper, this object when passed through `is.vector` simply fails. If you look up the documentation for `is.vector`

```
?is.vector
```

you'll see this

> `is.vector(x)` returns TRUE if x is a vector of the specified mode
> having no attributes other than names. For mode="any", see ‘Details’.

which tells us why it returns `FALSE` and why `fitdistrplus::descdist` throws the error.

---

There's countless ways to achieve what you want, one way being:

```
x = read.csv("<your_data_dir>/Trees_In_Camden.csv")
fitdistrplus::descdist(data = x$Height.In.Metres[!is.na(x$Height.In.Metres)])
```

Here I simply access the relevant column in the data frame (using its name) and then subset that numeric vector using `is.na()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So, how can I exclude the NAs in order to use fitdistrplus::descdist?

Comment: @KώσταςΚούδας See the edit above.

Comment: I understood! I made some minor changes because I was still encountering errors, but your help was instrumental in finding the solution. Thank you very much!